# 404 Error in laravel 5.1 Wamp

Tags: laravel

I am beginner in Laravel. I used Laravel 5.1 in Wamp Server (Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12)

I received the 404 Not Found Error, when I called the page like

http://localhost/laravel/public/login

[image]

```
Route::get('login', function() {
//return View::make('login');
return 'Hello World';  });
```

vhost.conf code

```
ServerAdmin local@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\laravel\public"
ServerName localhost
ErrorLog "logs/AuthorityController.www-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/AuthorityController.www-access.log" common


   <Directory "C:\wamp\www\laravel\public">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: do u get any out put above ur code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://localhost/login
may be it helps you, i hope :). And check that you vhost in appache is set to `.../your_laravel_project/public` folder

**UPDATE**
Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add line at the bottom:

```
127.0.0.1 myproject.dev
```

Then, in your appache `httpd.conf` file you shoud uncoment line:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

BONUS: You can also switch directory with you projects in lines (for instance i have my projects in 'F:/Code'):

```
DocumentRoot "F:/Code"
<Directory "F:/Code">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Next step, in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` you should have:

```
<VirtualHost myproject.dev> 
    DocumentRoot "F:\Code\myproject\public"
    ServerName myproject.dev
    ServerAlias myproject.dev
    <Directory "F:\Code\myproject\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then reset appache. And when you go to your browser and put `http://myproject.dev` you should see your page :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that anymore. Don't include that. What you do is put a view file (your 404 error view) called `404.blade.php` in your `resources/views/errors` folder and Laravel will handle 404 errors for you.